# Building Fence Adjacent to Neighbors (Lewis County WA)

Tags: fence, building-regulations

We have been having trouble with our neighbors with noxious weeds and property line disputes. They want to move their fence a foot after having the line resurveyed to the property line, which we don't care. We want to however build a privacy fence as close as we can to that fence but we aren't sure how far legally we must be away from that fence. I've tried to look up legal help for it but can never find it and don't want to have to go to a lawyer if I don't have to. Any ideas?

Comment: go to city hall, or the equivalent government office ... your question is off topic here ... please come back when you have problems with the fence construction itself

Comment: Good fences make good neighbors

Comment: Usually on your own land, which ends at the property line you can built whatever, as long as the locals in charge permit it.  Be aware that the space between the two fences might become dead space if you can't get between the two fences for maintenance.  If on the line your neighbours might go for privacy fence if you both pay half.  One fence for half the cost of two fences.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about local code and legal issues are [off topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You could offer the neighbor to share the cost of moving the fence it you are permitted to attach your privacy modification to it.  This might cost less than building a whole new privacy fence.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see how you can have a property line dispute if the land has been surveyed, unless you disagreed with the survey report.  If that is the case, you would have to pay to have your own survey done.

To answer your question first – @crip659 provided the general rules about a fence between two neighbors and the fence you build must comply with your local building code, i.e, height, appearance, type, etc.

You should be able to build your own fence up to the property line.  Here are some other considerations on your neighbor’s fence.

1. He can only build up to the property line without your permission.  His post holes and support must be fully within his property line.
2. His fence can straddle the property line only with your permission.  If you are willing to grant permission, you would have the prerogative to agreed on:

   a.  The type of fence

   b.  The appearance on your side

   c.  If you are willing to pay part of the cost

   d.  If you are willing to help pay for maintenance

   e.  If you two cannot come to an agreement, he would have to do point 1 – build the fence entirely within his property line

If the neighbor did build the fence on his property, why would you build your own fence? His fence resolved your main issue of weeds and the need for a privacy fence.  The only reason for building your own fence next to his would be that you didn’t like it appearance or the fence did not provide enough privacy.  For privacy, I would plant thick shrubs that would not have the height limitations of a fence.

In my backyard, I have two fences adjacent to each other with the dead space between them that is not accessible.  Not because of bad neighbors, but different builders and time of development.  The land behind my house were developed 5 years later after my neighborhood was built.  The new builder built a new fence next to the old backyard fences for a ¼ mile with about 6” of space between the old and new fences.

Comment: Can you specify is this is _general_ knowledge, code in _your_ neck of the woods, or if you've confirmed that this is actually code in Lewis County, WA, as the OP specified. I agree that this is _generally_ very good advice, but the OP needs to know if this is correct for _his_ locale. (Of course, he should probably contact his local building commission to confirm what the local laws are...)

Comment: It is as stated by @crip659, just check with (asks) the local building permit agency if there are any restrictions without a need for a lawyer.  If OP decides to build his own fence,  the permit would only be granted if he is allowed to build up to the property line otherwise the request would have to be modified to comply with the local code.